# Can I create a div having a height that is a percentage of the window and maintains constant proportions?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to make a fixed proportion website that scales to the window size. I realize I will get varying margins on the sides, and I'll not be able to expand the page to fit content; those constraints are OK.

I want to make the site in a div where height is 90% of the window height, and width is 150% of the window height. So, the div scales but maintains its proportions. It seems like this is a job for jQuery.

Comment: This is not "a place for jquery". It is a programming Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var $window = $(window),
    $wrapper = $('#wrapper');

$window.resize(function(){
    $wrapper.css({
        width: $window.height() * 1.5,
        marginTop: $window.height() * .05
    });
}).resize();
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsBRw/) (resize the bottom-right pane to see it in action).

---

**Note:** as is, the wrapper div might actually be wider than the viewport.
If that's not what you want, you'll have to add logic to prevent that.

Comment: that was fast.. and exactly the script I needed!

Comment: I do need to get rid of the scroll bars, which I assume can be accomplished by adding a negative margin to the div equal to the top margin. I tried 
`marginBottom: - ($window.height() * .05)` 
but that didn't do it.

Comment: got the scrollbars to disappear with the following CSS: `body { height:100% } html { height:95% }` No changes to Joseph's javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty close, the `marginTop` property isn't quite being set right:

```
$(function () {
    var percent = 50,
        ratio   = 1.6;
    $(window).bind('resize', function () {
        var $this  = $(this),
            width  = $this.width(),
            height = Math.floor(width / ratio);

        $('#window-id').css({
            width      : Math.floor(width * (percent / 100)),
            height     : Math.floor(height * (percent / 100)),
            marginLeft : Math.floor((1 - (percent / 100)) / 2 * $this.width()),
            marginTop  : Math.abs((height - $this.height()) / 2)
        });
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

This binds to the `resize` event for the `window` object, whenever a `resize` event is fired, the `#window-id` element will be re-sized and re-positioned.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WwVxY/1/